# How to color a specific point in a scatterplot by using a selectInput using RShiny and ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly, ggplotly

I have invented a dataset with 3 variables:

1. Name of the student (`grades$Name`)
2. Math's grades (`grades$math`) and
3. Number of classes that they have attended (`grades$participation`).

With this df, I have created a scatterplot to analyze the relationship between grades and participation of different students with ggplot2. What I want is to create an interactive plot where I can visualize each student and their respective grade and participation. That's why used ggplotly to generate an interactive plot, so I can visualize each student with their respective grade/participation. Here is the syntaxis:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
library(shiny)

#Data frame
grades <- data.frame(Name = c("A","B","C","D",
                              "E","F","G","H",
                              "I","J","K","L"), math=c(10,15,20,05,
                                                        18,11,08,03,
                                                        19,05,06,13),participation = c(10,10,10,4,
                                                                                       8,5,4,2,
                                                                                       8,6,5,6))
#Graph
Graph <- grades %>% ggplot(aes(math, participation, label=Name)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method= "lm",se=F) +
  labs(title= "Grades and Participation of students", 
       x="Grades in math", y="Participation in math's class")
#Interactive graph
iGraph <- ggplotly(Graph, tooltip= c("Name", "x", "y"))
print(iGraph)
```

Nevertheless, I want to include a "Search Bar" where I can type the name of the student (`grades$name`) so the point that represents that specific student will be painted with other color (in this case I chose red). I read that in order to incorporate functionality I need to create a ShinyApp. I am a very beginner with ShinyApp so I've tried to look for the solution but nothing is working. Here is the code that I have been using:

```
ui <- fluidPage( 
  titlePanel("Grades and Participation"),
  selectInput(inputId = "name", 
              label = "Student's Name",
              choices = grades$Name,
              selected = "A"),
  plotlyOutput("scatterplot")
  )

#Server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  #Subset of filter data
  filter_data <- reactive({grades %>% filter(Name %in% input$name)})
  
  output$scatterplot <- renderPlotly({iGraph + 
  geom_point(filter_data, aes(color= "red"))})
}

#Shiny
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The error message that is showing me is the following:

```
Warning: Error in geom_point: `mapping` must be created by `aes()`
  111: <Anonymous>
  110: signalCondition
  109: signal_abort
  108: rlang::abort
  107: cli::cli_abort
  106: validate_mapping
  105: layer
  104: geom_point
  103: renderPlotly [#6]
  102: func
   99: shinyRenderWidget
   98: func
   85: renderFunc
   84: output$scatterplot
    3: runApp
    2: print.shiny.appobj
    1: <Anonymous>
```

I think that one problem is that I can't add another layer of the ggplot after creating the ggplotly, but in that case how can I make the graph change the color of the individual point (aka student) that I write in the "search bar" of the ShinyApp?

What I want is to show the interactive graph made with ggploty (so I can move the cursor through the chart and see the grades and participation of each student) but also I want to be able to search for every student with the "search bar". The ideal output would be that the graph changes the color of only the student that I've selected (for example if I specify Student "A" that point should change to red) while the rest should remain the same.

Comment: Try with `geom_point(data = filter_data, ...)`. Otherwise the dataset is assigned to `mapping=`.

Comment: You'll need to call your reactive `filter_data()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the information of which name is selected in the dataset before plotting it. To do that, we move the ggplot and ggplotly calls into the `renderPlotly()` function. Add a `selected` variable that is TRUE for the selected name and use that for the coloring of the points in `geom_point()`.
`scale_color_manual()` controls the colors and with `guides(color = "none")` we can hide the legend.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
library(shiny)

#Data frame
grades <- data.frame(Name = c("A","B","C","D",
                              "E","F","G","H",
                              "I","J","K","L"), math=c(10,15,20,05,
                                                       18,11,08,03,
                                                       19,05,06,13),participation = c(10,10,10,4,
                                                                                      8,5,4,2,
                                                                                      8,6,5,6))



ui <- fluidPage( 
  titlePanel("Grades and Participation"),
  selectInput(inputId = "name", 
              label = "Student's Name",
              choices = grades$Name,
              selected = "A"),
  plotlyOutput("scatterplot")
)

#Server

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  #Subset of filter data
  filter_data <- reactive({grades %>% filter(Name %in% input$name)})
  
  output$scatterplot <- 
    renderPlotly({
      
      #Graph
      Graph <- grades %>%
        mutate(selected = Name == input$name) |>
        ggplot(aes(math, participation, label = Name)) +
        geom_point(aes(color = selected)) +
        scale_color_manual(values = c("TRUE" = "red", "FALSE" = "black")) +
        guides(color = "none") +
        geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = F) +
        labs(title = "Grades and Participation of students",
             x = "Grades in math", y = "Participation in math's class")
      #Interactive graph
      ggplotly(Graph, tooltip = c("Name", "x", "y"))
      
    })
}

#Shiny
shinyApp(ui, server)
```